Spring boot container refused to connect with postgres db container with ip address & hostname
My Docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: dockerSpringDB
    depends_on:
      - mydb
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynet

  mydb:
    ports:
      - 5439:5432
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresDB
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - my_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mypostgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    networks:
      - mynet
volumes:
  my_volume:
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge

Try to connect with below URLS in intelij :
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres.
Getting success while running in the local spring boot app.
But after containerized spring boot app getting error like below in the container logs.

2024-09-03T17:28:01.811Z  WARN 1 --- [spring-boot-postgres-docker] [
main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Connection to
localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct
and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.] [n/a]
2024-09-03T17:28:01.822Z  INFO 1 --- [spring-boot-postgres-docker] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping
service [Tomcat]
2024-09-03T17:28:01.875Z  INFO 1 --- [spring-boot-postgres-docker] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-09-03T17:28:01.923Z ERROR 1 --- [spring-boot-postgres-docker] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               :

Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path

resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Connection to
localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct
and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.] [n/a]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)
~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar!/:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar!/:6.1.12]

After research found that host name should be get through docker inspect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5433/postgres   Got this IP address from docker inspect  << container ID >>
found this: "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"
Error in local IDE it self with ip address.
Also tried with servicename as db host. mydb. same old error in local it self.
Am bit wondering with spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres  in my local IDE working fine. After containerized only getting connecction refused error.
remaining 2 tries are failed in local & in container
Am using docker desktop
Need help from any champ.
Spring boot app need to connect with docker db container without any connection refused errro

You cannot use 1 configuration to run locally and run in a docker container. Locally you need localhost in docker you need to service name. Modify your docker file and add SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=<the url need> as an environment parameter (this will override the one from the application.properties.
